# The correct way to add separators in lists

Tags: html, accessibility

I’m adding a thematic break inside a unordered list and I’m wondering what is the correct way to do that that will keep the list accessible and semantically correct.

What I would like to do would look something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>These</li>
  <li>Items</li>
  <li>Are of</li>
  <li>One kind</li>

  <hr />

  <li>But these</li>
  <li>Are of</li>
  <li>Another kind</li>
</ul>
```

However the `<hr>` element is not allowed as a child of `<ul>` even though it is semantically correct as a thematic break in the list items.

Another option would be to include the `<hr>` inside an extraneous `<li>`:

```html
<li><hr /></li>
```

However that would be lying about the number of list items. I only have 7 items in the example above, but this would announce 8.

My third option would be to change the role of the `<li>` to [separator](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#separator):

```html
<li role="separator"></li>
```

This both semantically correct and [allowed in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), but I’m wondering if this is accessible. I.e. will assistive technology announce the correct number of items in the list *and* convey the thematic break among the list items.

Comment: why not make them different lists? perhaps under a single parent?

Comment: After doing some testing it looks like <li role="separator"></li> does what I want (at least with Orca screen reader on Firefox). It omits the separator from the list item count (i.e. announces “list with 7 items”) and when navigating to the separator it announces it as a separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would break it into 2 lists, perhaps with a surrounding one to keep them semantical related.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Two questions: Won’t this be worse UX for assistive technology not knowing how many total items are in the list until they’ve reached the bottom list? And will this adequately convey the thematic break to users with screen readers?

Comment: @RúnarBerg - Presumably the `<hr/>`  is included for a reason, right?  What is it separating in the list?  Can it be logically and semantically conceptualized as two separate lists?  If so, then I'd say this answer is correct...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Think of it as an action menu with 5 items, the last item could be a logout action which is thematically different from the other items (e.g. profile, settings, help, etc.) As a user with a screen reader would you rather have a list with two items announced and then on investigating both items see a list with 4 items, and a list with 1 item. Or would you want a single list with 5 items, and before the last item be announced a separator?

Comment: @RúnarBerg Sure... that's a fair point... I suppose if they are better understood as a single list, you could always fake the `<hr/>` with a border on one edge of one of the items... although it makes for slightly wonkier markup...

Comment: You essentially want an `<optgroup>` type feature from the `<select>` element, which unfortunately doesn't exist for lists :-(